# Dominated convergence theorem application unsure of limit and dominating function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Compute

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} (1 + x^n\sin(xn))^{1/3} dx$$

The problem I'm running into is that $x^n$. If I say $\sin(xn) \leq 1$, I can't take that limit because the power n goes to infinity. One trick I used in a previous problem was that $\sin(xn) \leq xn$. However, this still leaves me a power of n, which makes the limit go to infinity. I also need to find a function that dominates this one, which I'm not quite sure how to do. Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0 \le x < 1$, then $\lim(x^n) = 0$, so since the sine is bounded, $\lim(x^n \sin(xn)) = 0$ for $0 \le x < 1$. The integrand is dominated by $2^{1/3}$, so you have what you need to apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Just to expand in case you need,  you only need to consider the $x$ values for that are in the bounds of integration.  The only value of $x$ that your integrand doesn't tend to 0 is $x=1$ which is where that $2$ came from

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Alan!